# TFS 2013 fails in running tests after build when deployment items are used

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration, integration-testing

We have setup a build that is triggered every night to execute the integrationstest we have created. The problem is that it seems to be a problem when execuring these tests. Several of theses tests uses files that are included in the test project and specifying these as deployment items.

There seems however to be a problem with this since we are getting the following error

Test Run deployment issue: Failed to copy file 'd:\Sources\Agent1\bin\Debug\xxx.pdf' to 'd:\Sources\Agent1\bin\Debug\xxxxx.pdf': System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'd:\Sources\Agent1\bin\Debug\xxx.pdf' because it is being used by another process.

All the tests are working when running them locally on our own machines.

After this warning emerges in the msbuild log the testrun just stops and hangs until the specified time for the agent has been reached and the buildserver kills the agent.

What can be the problem and how can this be solved so we can get the integrationstest to run again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TFS Build by default places the build outputs in a different location then when you build locally in VS.  When you build locally it puts them in [projectdir]\bin\Debug.  when you use TFS Build it has a folder structure like so:

```
[workspace dir]\Sources\[projectdir]
[workspace dir]\Binaries\
```

TFS Build redirects the build outputs to the Binaries folder.  So if you have custom actions looking in \bin\debug it won't find them.